# REST : Static API design

Tags: java, design, rest, api-design

Lets say, I have a scenario where I have to expose an api to fetch **supported shirt sizes**(`small` , `medium` and `large`)

My initial thought was `/v1/shirts/sizes` - But this clashes with the existing fetch shirt by id api. `v1/shirts/:id`.

My friend is suggesting, we can have resource named **metadata**, which can be used to list all static information throughout our application. Something like
`/v1/metadata/shirtsizes` , `/v1/metadata/languages` etc.

But I am not happy with having `metadata` api since it have completely unrelated sub-resources(shirtsizes , supported-lanugages)

How to handle this scenario? Is there any way to achieve it?

Comment: Are there any constraints on the `:id` placeholder? E.g. if the ID is numeric, then `sizes` won't conflict. Alternatively just add an endpoint like `/v1/shirt-sizes`. Not as elegant, still better than introducing a metadata concept without strong justification.

Comment: Id is string , which can contain a special char `-`

Comment: v1/shirtsizes seems logical

Answer (score 5):

REST doesn't care what spelling conventions you use for your URI.  An identifier like

```
/ac8a98b3-553a-4eb3-9878-e143f3f52a4e
```

is *fine*.

REST doesn't particularly care about clashes with "fetch by id".  You are allowed to write request handlers that branch.  See, for example, the [rails routing conventions](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html), which specifically use hints that sit in the same path segment as identifiers

```
/photos/new
/photos/:id
```

REST doesn't particularly care what information is encoded within the path or within the query

```
/v1/shirts/:id
/v1/shirts?sizes
```

(Which is not to say this distinction doesn't matter - in particular, HTML form processing treats the hierarchical path elements differently than the non-hierarchical query.  But the difference between the two is purely mechanical.)

REST certainly doesn't care about the order of path segments

```
/v1/sizes/shirts
```

Again, that's *fine*.

(We design path hierarchies not for the information that they communicate, but instead so that we can conveniently leverage standardized [resolution of relative references](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-5.2).)

Part of the point of REST is that the identifiers are just identifiers; the general purpose components don't attempt to extract information from them.  So you can use any spellings that make sense locally.